# Drupal menu , duplicate node content

Tags: drupal, drupal-routes

In drupal 6 the node menu is `$items['node/%node']`. This should give a url like `www.sitename.com/node/1`
but when accessing `www.sitename.com/node/1/something` again the same menu is called, thus making the contents of **www.sitename.com/node/1/something** as duplicate of `www.sitename.com/node/1`

is there any way to stop this happen

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should add new menu path in hook_menu in your module which will override this path. Should be something like:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['node/%node/something'] => array(
        'title' => 'My title',
        'page callback' => 'my_custom_callback',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // use this if you want to add new tab
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK // use this if you want just callback function
    );
    return $items;
}
```

After that you will have to write function `my_custom_callback` which will perform your code for this page.

```
function my_custom_callback($nid = null) {
    // do your code
    return $output
}
```